# Plot the image of a function $\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: plotting, regions

Given a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, I would like to plot the set $\mathrm{Im}(f)\cap R\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $R$ is a rectangular set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (ie. the plot range that I want to use). ParamatricPlot only seems to work for functions $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$. I could, for example, create a big table of values of $f$ and then plot those. However, I'd prefer to see a filled out region in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: A concrete example function (simple but capturing the essential features of $f$) would certainly help others to help you...

Answer (score 3):

If you're mapping points from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, you could just use a table.

```
step = 0.1;
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := {c a - b^2 - d^3 b,   b c^2 - a^2 d}
pts = DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[Table[
     f[a, b, c, d], {a, -1, 1, step}, {b, -1, 1, step}, {c, -1, 1, 
      step}, {d, -1, 1, step}], 3]];
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: 4d to 2d regular plot]

You could also randomly sample a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ instead of generating a regular grid. This breaks up some of the regularity. And you might consider using a `SmoothDensityHistogram` to visualize the density of the points.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := {c a - b^2 - d^3 b,   b c^2 - a^2 d}
pts = f @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20000, 4}];
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: 4d to 2d random plot]

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you think there's a way where I can see a filled out region, similarly to parametric plot?

Comment: What would that look like though? I imagine taking small 4d-cubes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and applying the function to get 2d-polygons on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: You could try a region plot on the PDF of the density. Something like ```kde = SmoothKernelDistribution[pts, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
RegionPlot[PDF[kde, {x, y}] > 0.01, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]```